# Failed to load XnaNative.dll

Tags: c#, xna

I've been using XNA to make games using C#. It has been working fine for at least the past year or so. However, suddenly, whenever I tried to run a game with any content item in it whatsoever, it gives me this error: "Building content threw FileNotFoundException: Failed to load XnaNative.dll. Please verify that you have the XNA Framework installed." I have reinstalled XNA and all of my editions of Visual Studio, and it still gives me this error. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, it turns out the problem was with only one or two projects: I fixed it by going to the "Content Build" tab in the project properties, then unchecking "Compress content pipeline output files".